# Huawei Appgallery - Not receiving comments for the APP through API

Tags: comments, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery

We are trying to retrieve comments ratings for an Application, however the API is returning an empty array even though there are 33 comments under the application

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the filter criteria used when 33 comments are queried on the AGC are the same as those configured on the interface.

Answer (score 0):

I Changed the period in the query to the request body and checked again, its worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the authorization token is not expired here [document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-obtain_token-0000001158365043)

Make sure required parameters are supplied. Here is reference [document](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-References/agcapi-com-rating-0000001133889426)

Otherwise, please provide more info for example the actual API you're called and the parameters you're supplied